# redirect to an another web page on browser refresh

Tags: javascript, html

how to redirect to another web-page on browser refresh. I know people will say its a bad thing but it is quite necessary for me, so please ca you tell me how to redirect the user to another webpage on refresh.

Comment: By `on browser refresh` do you mean when someone presses Reload or f5?

Comment: any form of refresh. reload/f5 . I know we can customise the f5 button i want to focus on esp browser reload icon click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `performance.navigation` to see if the page has just been refreshed, and if it has, just assign to `window.location.href` accordingly:

```
if (performance.navigation.type === 1) {
  // page was just refreshed:
  window.location.href = 'https://some-redirect';
} else {
  // rest of your Javascript
}
```

Comment: brilliant. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: How do we achieve this in flutter web anyone ?

Comment: @SanalKv this has an idea for Flutter web https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73053668/flutter-web-how-to-redirect-to-root-page-or-any-other-page-when-browser-is-r?noredirect=1&lq=1